# Android - Get id from Geocoder location

Tags: java, android, geolocation, maps, geo

UPDATED: If I try to use ZIP CODE I'll get  neighborhood code. And I want something to identify NEW YORK not the neighborhood.
[image]

I'm using geolocation (`geocoder`) in my app, and I compare the city name that geocode gives me with a name I already have in my database.

For example, if the user has phone language in English the result would be something like this:

```
DATABASE: New York
APP RESULT: New York (MATCH)
```

But if user has phone language in Spanish the result won`t match:

```
DATABASE: New York
APP RESULT: Nueva York (NO MATCH)
```

Is there any way to obtain a `UNIQUE ID` for every `CITY` instead of `names`, something like `"CITYNAME = 0001q5"`?

Comment: Every city has a uniquie ZipCode, you can use that.

Comment: Hey,I updated my answer. From geocode I only can get  neighborhood zip code. Is there any way to get something to identify new york instead neighborhood?